# How do I know that url call comes from Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to share a page at Facebook, but the issue is that a page is for logged in users only. And while trying to get a page's info FB doesn't receive needed data.
So the question is how do I know in PHP that it is FB who's calling a page?
$_REQUEST or $_SERVER?
Thanks for advance.

Comment: Where do you want to share that page - in a closed group where all members have a login to your site or something? Because publicly sharing login-protected pages does not make much sense IMHO - it only leads to frustration for users that follow such a link in their newsfeed, only to be then told this content is not available to them ...

Comment: Thanks!
I've already found a solution...